# php: best system/cms for building social community system?

Tags: content-management-system, system, social-networking

our company needs to build up a professional social community site with extensive features like:
profiles/groups/add friend, image + video upload, articles + tagging, activity stream,
login/interfaces to social sites like facebook, twitter, foursquare, vimeo ..

what would be the most powerful system/extension?
the most important factor would be: speed!
as we also want to do most of the gui customizing by php on our own, the cms/system shouldn't be too static.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to use [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org) + [Jom Social](http://jomsocial.com)